# Text Fade Effect in .NET Compact Framework

Tags: c#, .net, windows, mobile, coldfusion

I am creating a windows mobile application where i would like to do a fade In / Fade out of text which is getting displayed on a form. I am using C# for this purpose.
Anyone can provide idea on this part?

Thanks in Advance
Regards
Biju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the first thing that comes to mind: have an array of colors - e.g. from your desired font color to whatever color makes the text invisible, and then use a timer to  change the color of your control text to each entry in the array in order. For example a 3 color fade effect ranging from white to black - fade in will be displaying white-gray-black, fade out will be black-gray-white!

Comment: THanks for the info. i have already tried it. but it's not smooth as i am trying to do this for a app where i am displaying the text as a karoke for a song and the timer has to change as per the song.

Comment: Maybe you could try it with a larger range of intermediate colors - maybe 20 or 30?

Comment: I am using the 15 now. will try to change it. 
I am using DrawString() to draw the string. the Text one will be displayed for 10 seconds and around 8 seconds the second text will start to appear and the first will start to disappear. The Problem is that it doesn't seems like a Smooth one and it looks raw